# Kotlin Coroutine returning after response.await()

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to make an android app connecting to api, and for that I am using Kotlin Coroutines and Retrofit. I was following this tutorial (https://android.jlelse.eu/android-networking-in-2019-retrofit-with-kotlins-coroutines-aefe82c4d777) trying to setup my own api, but I stumbled on a problem. I can't get any data from api because I can't process response.

I don't know much about coroutines, so I don't understand whats the problem here. If I run debug and go line by line it is working perfectly each time, but if I run the app, it only prints TestPoint1. Also it doesn't throw any error and response is always 200 OK. I have tried to combine

```
val standings = service.getStandings()
```

and

```
val response = standings.await()
```

into one line, after which it doesn't work on debug either. It continues on code after launched coroutine.

```
val service = ApiFactory.footballApi

GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val standings = service.getStandings()
    try {
        Log.d("TAG", "TestPoint1")
        val response = standings.await()
        Log.d("TAG", "TestPoint2")
        if(response.isSuccessful){
            //store data
        }else{
            Log.d("MainActivity ",response.errorBody().toString())
        }
    }catch (e: Exception){
        Log.d("TAG", "Error")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the `Dispatchers.Main` to `Dispatchers.IO` . You can't make that request on the main thread . 
The coroutines require a coroutine context in order to know in what thread they are going to run . For that , the `Dispatchers` class offer you some options . Currently you are making the request in the `Dispatchers.Main` which you cannot do because fetching data from the API , requires another thread . IO is the right thread for network calls .

**Note :**

Also please check : Internet permission, Internet connection .